# Rspec Mocks: mock / yield the block from a method call

Tags: lambda, rspec, mocking

I've got this code:

```
Net::SSH.start(@server, @username, :password => @password) do |ssh|
            output = ssh.exec!(@command)
            @logger.info 'SSH output: '
            @logger.info output
        end
```

I can mock the SSH.Start using RSpec's mock framework like this, to tell me that I've started the SSH session:

```
Net::SSH.should_receive(:start).with("server", "user", :password => "secret") do
            @started = true
        end
```

this tells me whether or not i've @started the ssh session. now I need to mock the ssh.exec! method, which is easy enough:

```
Net::SSH.should_receive(:exec!).with("command")...
```

but how do I yield / call the block that contains the ssh.exec! method call, since I have mocked the SSH.start method? there's probably some simple method I can call to execute this block, but I don't know what it is and can't find any really good explanations / documentation on rspec's mocking framework.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Net::SSH.should_receive(:start).with(
  "server", "user", :password => "secret").and_yield(
  "whatever value the block should yield")
```

Not sure why you need to set `@started`, since the `should_receive` verifies that the method has been called.

Comment: didn't know that about should_receive... is there any good documentation on this stuff? my google-fu is failing me...

also - what if I don't care about the return value of the yielded block? I just want it to be executed, so that i can call should_receive on the ssh.exec! method.

Comment: That's what `should_receive` means: if it isn't received, the test will fail.

As far as documentation, the RSpec Book is excellent. I recommend it both for learning to use RSpec, and for learning about BDD in general.

Comment: Oh, and you may be able to call `#and_yield()` without an argument.